# Como fazer com que quando o botão seja pressionado ele continua com a cor diferente

Tags: html, css, button

Olá, eu gostaria que quando fosse pressionado o botão, ele mudasse de cor e continuasse assim até que outro seja pressionado.
Eu tentei com o `:focus`, mas caso pressione outro elemento a cor volta.

Botões:

```
<input type="button" class="button" name="button1" id="button1" value="button1">
<input type="button" class="button" name="button2" id="button2" value="button2">
```

CSS:

```
.button
{
    background: #76c764;
    height: 30px;
    width: 49%;
    border: none;
    border-radius: 5px;
}
.button:focus
{
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 0;
    border: 0 none;
    outline: 0;
    background: #69e673;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Podes fazer isso com JavaScript ou com HTML e CSS, mas aí com algum engenho...

Se fizeres com HTML tens de mudar um pouco a estrutura e poderia ser assim, mas é meio "hack".

```css
fieldset {
 border: none;
}
button {
 border: none;
 border-radius: 5px;
 background: #eef;
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
}

fieldset label {
 display: block;
 padding: 10px;
 font-size: 15px;
}

fieldset input[type="radio"] {
 display: none;
}
fieldset input[type="radio"]:checked + button {
 background-color: #aaf;
}
```

```html
<fieldset>
    <input type="radio" name="algo" id="um">
    <button>
        <label for="um">clica-me</label>
    </button>
</fieldset>
<fieldset>
    <input type="radio" name="algo" id="dois">
    <button>
        <label for="dois">clica-me</label>
    </button>
</fieldset>
```

Com JavaScript seria mais simples:

```js
var radios = document.querySelectorAll('.radio');
function toggleButton(el) {
  for (var i = 0, l = radios.length; i < l; i++) {
    var fn = radios[i] == el ? 'add' : 'remove';
    radios[i].classList[fn]('focus');
  }
}
```

```css
.button {
  background: #76c764;
  height: 30px;
  width: 49%;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 5px;
}

.button.focus {
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 0;
  border: 0 none;
  outline: 0;
  background: #69e673;
}
```

```html
<input type="button" class="button radio" name="button1" id="button1" value="button1" onClick="toggleButton(this);">
<input type="button" class="button radio" name="button2" id="button2" value="button2" onClick="toggleButton(this);">
```